# ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFound errors with UCanAccess

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

The JDBC-ODBC Bridge is no longer included in Java 8 so I tried [UCanAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390), but I am having trouble with that. Here is my code:

```
  package jdbc;
  import java.sql.*;

 public class jdbc  
 {
    Connection con;
    Statement st;

    jdbc()
    {  
        try
        {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://P:/eclipseWorkspace/databases/signup.accdb");
        st=con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO signup (firstName,lastName,email,password)     VALUES ('rocky','balboa','rocky@gmail.com','pop')");
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


}

class main
{
     public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new jdbc();
    }
}
```

I have included some external jars as shown in the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMb1q.png

When i run it, it gives me a stack trace with ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFound errors as shown here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7kZQ.png

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please mention the loads of errors that you are receiving!

Comment: [Class.forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is not longer supported? The documentation say something other.

Comment: errors are shown in the image link (the last one).

Comment: When you unzipped the UCanAccess distribution it created a `lib/` folder with the compatible versions of the required dependencies. One of those is `commons-lang-2.6.jar` but I see from your screenshot that you are using `commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar`. Try replacing that one with the 2.6 version in the UCanAccess `lib/` folder and see if that helps.

Comment: @Gord i did as you said. And now i have new errors.   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SIGNUP  
Old ones were fixed , so thanks for that.

Comment: All fixed guys. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UCanAccess has several dependencies, one of which is commons-lang-2.x (2.4 or newer). You are using commons-lang3-3.3.2 in your project, so UCanAccess (actually Jackcess) cannot find the commons-lang-2.x classes.

When you unzipped the UCanAccess distribution it created a `lib/` folder with the compatible versions of the required dependencies. You need to replace the `commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar` reference in your project with `commons-lang-2.6.jar` from the UCanAccess `lib/` folder.